# Icons not appearing on map?

Tags: far-cry-4

I have searched all over the map to find the remaining 30 propaganda posters. Finding the first 120 were fine, but the last 30 posters don't seem to have an icon on the map. (I have completed all propaganda center missions and all campaign missions)

This glitch is not exclusive to propaganda icons. When playing co-op, me and my friend were trying to complete all of the assassination missions. I was looking on the map for the last one and I could not find it. My friends found it and put a waypoint on it. When I went to see where it was on the map (I was zoomed in all the way), there was no icon. Only the waypoint. When hovering over the waypoint the screen read "ASSASSINATION." We completed the mission fine, but the icon was not on my map.

NOTE: I realize that not all icons show up when you are zoomed out on the map screen...I'm not that stupid but I know someone will tell me to zoom in...

I was wondering if anyone else has this issue where some quests/missions appear just fine while others have no icon on the map, making them impossible to find unless you try and hover over every inch of the map.

Im not sure if this is relevant but I'm playing on PC.

Comment: wouldn't surprise me if some stuff was overlooked during the creation of the game. Also in farcry 3 you needed to buy maps to be able to see the collectibles so that might be it, I don't own 4 so just speculation.

Comment: I think you have to unlock zones of the map.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the map options that all the icon are checked. This means they’ll show up on the map. If they are and they still don’t show up make sure you have all the maps.

Answer (score 0):

Like Paralytic said, you can just buy the maps in game menu and it will show you exactly where each location is. The only thing I've read that was bugged was the unknown locations. But those don't count against your progress anyway. Searching through google doesn't indicate anyone has had this kind of bug after the November update. I know certain icons show up at certain zoom levels when you're looking at the large map. But finding all achievements is possible:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I personally never went through the effort of finding everything in the game, because It was pretty pointless, unless you need to complete everything to get the gun like Outposts or Fortresses seen in the first image.